# LogitModelFit bias term when using design matrix

Tags: fitting, probability-or-statistics

I'm using the `LogitModelFit` function with a 32-columns design matrix and 0 or 1 output vector: `LogitModelFit[{datax, datay}]`.

The fits seems to work, however the fit function has no bias term, unlike the other examples provided in the documentation.

For example, when I apply the fit function to the origin `ConstantArray[0, 32]`, a value of `0.5` is returned.

The documentation specifies that for a design matrix m and response vector v, the model is $\hat{v}=1/(1+\exp(\mathbf m.\beta))$ (so no intercept term).

I don't understand how this is standard behaviour. How can I change it ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so the answer is simply to add an intercept column of 1s to the design matrix (here `X`):

```
X = ArrayFlatten[{{1,X}}];
fit = LogitModelFit[{X, y}];
results = MapThread[fit, Transpose[X]];
```

To test the hypothesis `fit` on a new datapoint however it's important to add `1` as its first parameter, ie. `fit` only works on the new feature space.